# How to deal with spatial autocorrelation AND temporal autocorrelation in a mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, autocorrelation, spatial, spatio-temporal

When creating a mixed model (or GLS) with spatiotemporal data, you can include correlation structure into your model to address autocorrelation. Spatial autocorrelation can be modelled for with correlation structures given form from spatial coordinates (tutorial here: https://rfunctions.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-to-identify-and-remove-spatial.html). The same thing can also be done for temporal autocorrelation, with correlation structures given form from a temporal variable (tutorial here: https://rpubs.com/markpayne/164550).
However, in the `nlme` R code, both methods inhabit the `‘correlation = CorStruc’` code which can only be used once in a model. Therefore, it appears that either only spatial autocorrelation or only temporal autocorrelation can be addressed, but not both (see example code below).

```
#neither autocorrelation considered
spatialmodel1 <- lme(rv ~ iv1+time  , random = ~1|group, 
              data = mydata)

#SAC considered
spatialmodel2 <- lme(rv ~ iv1+time  , random = ~1|group, 
                     data = mydata,correlation = corSpher(form = ~ X + Y, nugget = T))

#TAC considered
spatialmodel3 <- lme(rv ~ iv1+time  , random = ~1|group, 
                     data = mydata,correlation = corAR1r(form = ~ time))

#SAC and TAC considered
spatialmodel4 <- lme(rv ~ iv1+time  , random = ~1|group, 
                     data = mydata,correlation = corSpher(form = ~ X + Y, nugget = T),
                     correlation = corAR1r(form = ~ time))

#spatialmodel4 fails, can't use correlation twice
```

My Question: Is there a way to incorporate both spatial and temporal autocorrelation into the same mixed model (or GLS), using multiple correlation structures in R? Moreover, does it make statistical sense to do so?
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you manually create a corStruct that involves both spatial and temporal terms?

Comment: thanks for the comment. yes in theory but adds more questions than it answers. The biggest one to my mind is 'why doesn't a corStruc for spatial and temporal terms already exist?'. Then 'how does one create a corStruc in R?'. And then 'how does one create the appropriate corStruc for my data?'. If you know any examples of how this has been done previously I'd appreciate being signposted to them.

Comment: INLA is a package for dealing with both spatial and temporal autocorrelation